# Reactjs error link should not be used outside router

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I am trying to put link in my header.js and the error occurs in index.js for some reason and i don't know how to fix it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Header
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Error message:

> 6 | ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Please show me where is your router/Browserrouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you should use `Link` component only in components that are inside your router. You should try and wrap the router component (`BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`, depending on which one you are using) on a higher level of the  components' hierarchy so that all components that need to use `Link` or `Route` will eventually be located under the `router` in the components' tree.

If you have `App` component which has `Header`, `Main` and `Footer` components inside (as an example), and you need to access `Link` in all children of `App`, then you can implement it this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from '../Main/Main';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Header from '../Footer/Footer';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

[React training guide](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) has very good examples that cover many different use cases of `react router` v4.